# C# FormatException Unhandled

Tags: c#

I'm working with Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express. I am currently trying to get my calculator to do addition and subtraction but I keep getting this error? I am using switch statements throughout the calculator.

```
        private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Storing the number on display in variables total1 for further use
        //Making addition happen before = is clicked
        total1 = total1 + double.Parse(textDisplay.Text);
        textDisplay.Text = textDisplay.Text + Add.Text;
        theOperator = "+";

    }

    private void Subtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        total1 = total1 + double.Parse(textDisplay.Text);
        textDisplay.Clear();

        theOperator = "-";

    }

    private void Equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      switch(theOperator)
      {
          case "+": //Addition
                    total1 = total1 + double.Parse(textDisplay.Text);---> error in this line
                    textDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                    total1 = 0;
                    break;

          case "-": //Subtraction
                    result = total1 - double.Parse(textDisplay.Text);--->error in this line
                    textDisplay.Text = result.ToString();
                    total1 = 0;
                    break;
```

Comment: What is the value of `textDisplay.Text` exactly and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: Can we assume that `total1`  is a double?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way. You can read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: I suggest to use Visual Studio's debugger and stop at this line and observe the value stored in `textDisplay.Text`... you will likely answer your own question.

Comment: I'd recommend adding `Trim()` to your `textDisplay.Text`. Having empty spaces would result in exceptions being thrown.

Comment: Soner Gönül thanks! textDisplay.Text is what i used to display the text and im not sure what currentculture is? The_Black_Smurf yes it is a double. DrewKennedy thanks, would it go at the end or before?

Answer (score 4):

On your problem lines, you have:

```
double.Parse(textDisplay.Text)
```

But in your `Add_Click` method you have this:

```
textDisplay.Text = textDisplay.Text + Add.Text;
```

I am hypothesizing that that your `Add` button label is *not* a number (likely it is either `Add` or `+`). So when you run the line above, you would get something like either:

- 1234Add
- 1234+

This will cause an exception in when you pass it to `double.Parse` because this function does not accept bad input (so unless `textDisplay.Text` is a number, it will give an error). You would want to use [`double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead if you want to test for bad input.

---

Here is an example on how to test for bad input:

```
private void Equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Remove the operator from the value we want to process.
    // It is expected this will be at the end.
    var userValue = textDisplay.Text;
    if (userValue.EndsWith(theOperator))
    {
        userValue = userValue.Substring(0, userValue.Length - theOperator.Length).Trim();
    }

    // Test for valid input.
    // Test our "userValue" variable which has the pending operator removed.
    double value;
    if (!double.TryParse(userValue, out value))
    {
        // Invalid input.
        // Alert the user and then exit this method.
        MessageBox.Show("A number was not entered.");
        return;
    }
    // If we get here, the "value" variable is a valid number.
    // Use it for calculations.

    ...
```

**Edit**

As a side note, you do have some logic issues with respect to how you are using and resetting `result` and `total1` in your OP. I'm not going to do your homework for you, but it would be a good idea to review your usages of these variables.

Comment: Thanks man! Add is what i called the + button. I used the line textDisplay.Text = textDisplay.Text + Add.Text to display the plus button on my calculator when pressed. If i deleted this line of code the addition works perfect but the calculator does not display the + button when pressed. I tried using double.TryParse and the same error came up. I am new to c# so I am not familiar with how it works. I am using switch statements, can i use if statements too?

Comment: @DylanGeaney - Either way, you have to have a valid number value to continue. If you want to show the operator in the display, but remove it when it comes to calculation time, see the updated answer.

Comment: @DylanGeaney - If this answered your question, please mark as the answer to close out the item. Cheers.